# Falha ao receber notificações Push nativas do Ionic 2

Tags: angular, push-notification, ionic2, google-cloud-messaging, sns

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo utilizando Ionic 2/Angular 2/Typescript.

Este aplicativo utiliza o plugin de notificações push nativas do Ionic 2 e o Google Cloud Message (GCM) em conjunto com o Amazon SNS.

O evento "on notification" frequentemente não está sendo disparado.

O SNS envia a mesma mensagem via push e via sms. As mensagens via sms sempre são recebidas.

Sempre preciso desinstalar o aplicativo e reiniciar a máquina virtual para funcionar. As vezes funciona, as vezes não. As vezes funciona apenas no início e depois para de receber notificações.

Alguém está com o mesmo problema ou sabe as possíveis causas?